# SonataUserBundle XML serializer config not working

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I have the `SonataUserBundle` and `JMSSerializerBundle` set up and running. Now i am trying to override the serializer configuration for `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User.`
The XML file i am using for this configuration was generated by the `SonataEasyExtendsBundle` in:
`Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Entity.User.xml` and looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serializer>
<!--
    This file has been generated by the EasyExtends bundle 
    ( http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends )

    @author <yourname> <youremail>
-->

    <class name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" exclusion-policy="all" xml-root-name="user">
        <property name="id" type="integer" expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="sonata_api_read,sonata_api_write,sonata_search" />
    </class>
</serializer>
```

I also configured `app/config/config.yml` to use that XML file:

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
        directories:
            ApplicationSonatUserBundle:
                path: @ApplicationSonataUserBundle/Resources/config/serializer
                namespace_prefix: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Model
```

Now according to the configuration i should only see the id field when the object gets serialized. But when i test this all fields are exposed. This is obviously a bad idea.
I am using `FOSRestBundle` to implement the API layer where this is being used. And if i run:

```
get_class($this->getUser())
//outputs Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

So `FOSUserBundle` is using the right `User` entity.

I have been looking at this for a couple of hours and can't find what's going wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally solved this, apparently you must reference the class where the properties actually reside. In this case i was trying to expose the property id which resides in FOS/UserBundle/Model/Entity. I ended up configuring properties for both Sonata/UserBundle/Model/User and the FOS user class. My XML now looks like this:

```
<serializer>
<class name="Sonata\UserBundle\Model\User" exclusion-policy="all" xml-root-name="user">
    <property name="dateOfBirth" type="DateTime" expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="firstname"   type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="lastname"    type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="website"     type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="locale"      type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="phone"       type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />

</class>
<class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User" exclusion-policy="all" xml-root-name="user">
    <property name="id"        type="integer"  expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="username"  type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="email"     type="string"   expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
    <property name="roles"     type="array"    expose="true" since-version="1.0" groups="profile" />
</class>
</serializer>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I want to expose username which resides in FOSUserBundle, but I can't get it working. How does you final app/config/config.yml look like? Does your Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Entity.User.xml look like what you've posted here? Thanks.

Comment: @PavelLinkesch, The above config was in Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Model.User.xml. If you have additional fields in your User entity class, these should be configured in Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Resources\config\serializer\Entity.User.xml. Default Sonata and FOSUser class properties can be configured as shown above in the Model.User.xml class